# Select forms of indexed variables from an expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to select some certain terms from a long expression. The expression contains parts like

```
k[1,2](k[3,4]+k[5,6])/k[2,3]
```

I hope to get all terms with the form of

```
k[a,b]+k[c,d]
```

where a, b, c, d, can be arbitrary integers. I tried

```
Select[expr,MemberQ[#,k[a_, b_]+k[c_, d_]]&]
```

but it didn't work. Is there a way to realized this?

In addition, I also want to use

```
FullSimplify[expr]/.k[a_, b_] :> k[b, a]
```

to simplify the expression but when I apply it to the expression, nothing is simplified. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: try `Cases[expr, Plus[_k, __k], All]`?

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot, it worked! Can you please explain why there are two underscores before the second k? Also, I need to extend the sequences to k[a,b,c,d] for further calculation but I don't know why this function failed if k has a length of 4.

Comment: ntly, posted  an answer explaining why `Plus[_k,_k]`  does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
expr = k[1, 2] (k[3, 4] + k[5, 6])/k[2, 3]
```

You can use `Cases` as follows:

```
Cases[expr, HoldPattern[_k + _k], All]
```

> {k[3, 4] + k[5, 6]}

```
expr2 = k[1, 2, 3, 4] (k[3, 4, 5, 1] + k[5, 6, 1, 7])/k[2, 3, 8, 9];
Cases[expr2, HoldPattern[_k + _k], All]
```

> {k[3, 4, 5, 1] + k[5, 6, 1, 7]}

**Note:** We cannot use the simpler pattern `_k + _k` because it evaluates to `2 _k` before pattern matching gets to work and `Cases` returns `{}` because no part of `expr` matches `2 _k`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! In addition, do you know why the Cases function does not work for expression consists of k[a,b,c,d]? For example, `k[1, 2,3,4] (k[3, 4, 5, 1] + k[5, 6, 1,7])/k[2, 3, 8, 9]`

Comment: @ntply, it does work for `expr2 = k[1, 2, 3, 4] (k[3, 4, 5, 1] + k[5, 6, 1, 7])/k[2, 3, 8, 9]` too.

Comment: Yeah, it does, I might have some typo before, Thanks again for your help :)